# Complete solution for a system of polynomial equations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, groebner-basis

A research question led to the following system of polynomial equations.

\begin{align*}
  & x^3 - x^2y + x^2z + x^2 - xy + xz + y^2 - yz - y = 0 \\
  & x^3z - 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + xz^2 - y^3 + y^2 - 2yz = 0 \\
  & x^4 - x^3y - 2x^3z + x^3 + x^2yz - x^2y + x^2z + xy^2 + xyz - xy - xz^2 - yz^2 = 0 \\
  & x^4z + x^4 - x^3y + x^2yz - x^2y + 2x^2z^2 + x^2z - x^2 - xy^2z + xy^2 + xy - y^2z + z^3 - z = 0
\end{align*}

I used the `poly_system` function in SymPy (a Python library for symbolic mathematics) to solve this system, and it returned the following solutions:

$$[(-1, 0, 0), (0, 0, -1), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0), (1, 2, 1), (2, 3, 0), (3, 6, 1)]$$

This was better than I had hoped, but I am concerned that the function may fail to find all solutions. How can I be certain that no other solutions exist?

Comment: Are you only interested in integer solutions? Either way this approach appears quite hopeless.

Comment: @orlp : This is also the solution set over the complexes.  So unless he was working over something unusual, ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Maple, I took a "plex($x,y,z$)" Groebner basis of the ideal generated by the left sides of your equations.  The result was
$$ \eqalign{&{z}^{5}-{z}^{3}
,\cr
&y{z}^{3}-y{z}^{2}
,\cr
&{y}^{2}{z}^{2}-{z}^{4}-{y}^{2}z-y{z}^{2}+yz+{z}^{2}
,\cr
&{y}^{3}z-7\,{z}^{4}-8\,{y}^{2}z+5\,y{z}^{2}+7\,yz+7\,{z}^{2}
,\cr
&{y}^{4}-18\,{z}^{4}-4\,{y}^{3}-23\,{y}^{2}z+27\,y{z}^{2}+3\,{y}^{2}+21
\,yz+18\,{z}^{2}
,\cr
&-3\,{z}^{4}+6\,x{z}^{2}+{y}^{3}-4\,{y}^{2}z+7\,y{z}^{2}-3\,{z}^{3}-4\,
{y}^{2}-yz+3\,{z}^{2}+3\,y+3\,z
,\cr
&6\,{z}^{4}+6\,xyz-{y}^{3}+{y}^{2}z-7\,y{z}^{2}+3\,{z}^{3}+4\,{y}^{2}-2
\,yz-6\,{z}^{2}-3\,y-3\,z
,\cr
&2\,x{y}^{2}-{y}^{3}+{y}^{2}z-{z}^{3}-2\,xy-2\,xz+y+z
,\cr
&3\,{z}^{4}+12\,{x}^{2}z-2\,{y}^{3}+5\,{y}^{2}z-11\,y{z}^{2}+6\,{z}^{3}
+8\,{y}^{2}-7\,yz-3\,{z}^{2}-6\,y-6\,z
,\cr
&6\,{x}^{2}y-{y}^{3}+{y}^{2}z+2\,y{z}^{2}-3\,{z}^{3}-6\,xy-6\,xz-2\,{y}
^{2}+4\,yz+3\,y+3\,z
,\cr
&-{z}^{4}+4\,{x}^{3}-{y}^{2}z+5\,y{z}^{2}-4\,{z}^{3}+4\,{x}^{2}-8\,xy+y
z+{z}^{2}+4\,z
\cr
}$$

From the first basis element, all solutions must have $z \in \{-1, 0, 1\}$.

If $z = -1$, the second basis element tells us $y=0$, and then the sixth gives us $x=0$.

If $z = 0$, the fifth basis element tells us $y \in \{0,1,3\}$.  If $y=0$ we get $x=0$ or $x=-1$ from the 11th basis element.  If $y=1$ we get $x=0$ or $x=1$ from the 10th basis element.  If $y=3$ we get $x=2$ from the 8th basis element.

If $z=1$, the fourth basis element gives us $y = 0$, $2$ or $6$.  If $y=0$, the 6th basis element gives us $x=0$.  If $y=2$, the 6th basis element gives us $x=1$.  If $y=6$, the 6th basis element gives us $x=3$.

Thus the listed solutions are the only ones.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I can answer my own question. SymPy reports that the ideal generated by these polynomials has the following Gröbner basis.

\begin{align*}
& 2xyz^2 + 2xyz - 2y^2z + 2xz^2 - yz^2 \\
&  y^2z^2 + 2xyz - 2y^2z + 2xz^2 - yz^2 \\
& 2xz^3 - yz^2 \\
& yz^3 - yz^2 \\
& z^4 + 2xyz - y^2z + 2xz^2 - yz - z^2 \\
& 4x^3 + 2xyz - 2y^2z + 2xz^2 + 5yz^2 - 4z^3 + 4x^2 - 8xy + 4z \\
& 2x^2y + 2xyz - 2y^2z + 4xz^2 + 3yz^2 - 2z^3 - 2xy - 2y^2 - 2xz + 2y + 2z \\
& 2xy^2 + 6xyz - 6y^2z + 12xz^2 + 7yz^2 - 4z^3 - 2xy - 4y^2 - 2xz - 4yz + 4y + 4z \\
& y^3 + 6xyz - 7y^2z + 12xz^2 + 7yz^2 - 3z^3 - 4y^2 - 4yz + 3y + 3z \\
& 4x^2z + 2xyz - 2y^2z + 6xz^2 + yz^2 - 4yz
\end{align*}

The Wikipedia article on the Gröbner basis has the following statement.

> Given the Gröbner basis G of an ideal I, it has only a finite number
>   of zeros, if and only if, for each variable x, G contains a polynomial
>   with a leading monomial that is a power of x (without any other
>   variable appearing in the leading term). If it is the case the number
>   of zeros, counted with multiplicity, is equal to the number of
>   monomials that are not multiple of any leading monomial of G. This
>   number is called the degree of the ideal.

Since the above condition is satisfied, we know that the system has exactly nine solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working over a field of characteristic zero, ...

Computing a Groebner basis for your system, which I duplicate so you can verify that I am working on the same system,
\begin{align*}
x^3 &-x^2 y+x^2 z+x^2-x y+x z+y^2-y z-y = 0 \\
x^3 z &-3 x^2 y+3 x y^2+x z^2-y^3+y^2-2 y z = 0 \\
x^4 &-x^3 y-2 x^3 z+x^3+x^2 y z-x^2 y+x^2 z+x y^2+x y z-x
   y-x z^2-y z^2 = 0 \\
x^4 z &+x^4-x^3 y+x^2 y z-x^2 y+2 x^2 z^2+x^2 z-x^2-x y^2 z+x y^2+x y-y^2 z+z^3-z = 0,
\end{align*}
we get (with variable order $x > y > z$) \begin{align*}
&z^5-z^3, \\
&y z^3-y z^2, \\
&y^2 z^2-y^2 z-y z^2+y z-z^4+z^2, \\
&y^3 z-8 y^2 z+5 y z^2+7 y z-7 z^4+7 z^2, \\
&y^4-4 y^3-23 y^2 z+3 y^2+27 y z^2+21 y z-18 z^4+18 z^2, \\
&6 x z^2+y^3-4 y^2 z-4 y^2+7 y z^2-y z+3 y-3 z^4-3 z^3+3 z^2+3 z, \\
&6 x y z-y^3+y^2 z+4 y^2-7 y z^2-2 y z-3 y+6 z^4+3 z^3-6 z^2-3 z, \\
&2 x y^2-2 x y-2 x z-y^3+y^2 z+y-z^3+z, \\
&12 x^2 z-2 y^3+5 y^2 z+8 y^2-11 y z^2-7 y z-6 y+3 z^4+6 z^3-3 z^2-6 z, \\
&6 x^2 y-6 x y-6 x z-y^3+y^2 z-2 y^2+2 y z^2+4 y z+3 y-3 z^3+3 z, \\
&4 x^3+4 x^2-8 x y-y^2 z+5 y z^2+y z-z^4-4 z^3+z^2+4 z
\end{align*}

The first tells us $z \in \{-1,0,1\}$ for any solution.

Taking $z=-1$ and simplifying the original system, the Groebner basis is $\{x, y\}$, meaning the only solution for this $z$ is $(0,0,-1)$.

Taking $z = 0$ and simplifying the original system, the Groebner basis is 
$$  \left\{x^5-2 x^4-x^3+2 x^2,-x^3-x^2+2 x y,-x^4+x^2+2 y^2-2 y\right\}  \text{.}  $$
The first tells us $x \in \{-1,0,1,2\}$.  Trying each of these, we get the solutions $(-1,0,0)$, $(0,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, $(1,1,0)$, and $(2,3,0)$.

Taking $z = 1$ and simplifying the original system, the Groebner basis is 
$$  \left\{x^3-4 x^2+3 x,y-2 x\right\}  \text{.}  $$
The first tells us $x \in \{0,1,3\}$ and for each of these, the second gives us $y$ in $(0,0,1)$, $(1,2,1)$, and $(3,6,1)$.

And there are no further solutions (over a field with characteristic zero).